# XML parsing: Extract nested nodes to display in JTable

Tags: java, xml, swing, parsing, nodes

I have an xml and part of it has the following structure.

```
<nodes>
   <node>
   </node>

   <node>
   </node>

</nodes>
```

Now there can be any number of `node` elements inside `nodes` . And a `node` in turn can contain more `nodes` elements which in turn can contain more `<node>` elements. it just goes on. Each `node` contains attributes as well.

I don't wanna jump into this without a proper design and end up in a royal mess, so what is the best way to extract this data? which I then need to display in a JTable most probably with a collapsible/expandable view. But that is another problem

Comment: It depends, do you want to be able to modify the original data (back into XML)?  Have you looked [Java API for XML Processing (JAXP)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/)? Have you looked into xPath?

Comment: No I don't need to do modify the data back into XML. And before looking into libraries I'm trying to come up with a design to tackle this problem.

Comment: SwingLab's SwingX library has a `JXTreeTable` which would most likely generate the structure you're looking for.  A basic "tree" structure will contain the data, you could use the SwingX's `TreeTableModel` directly or use it to wrap your own structure

Answer (score 0):

DOM and XPATH do the job:

```
String xml= // your xml
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
NodeList nodes_field_to_insert=document_to_insert.getElementsByTagName("node");
for (int k = 0; k < nodes.getLength(); k++) {
// Do what you want with that
```

Nevertheless, You have to read the API, and example.

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/org.w3c.dom.NodeList

hope it helps